# How can I model indentations on a surface?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to learn blender, and for fun trying to make a model of a bottle. The bottle shape is no problem, but the bottle has a special pattern in its material that needs to be cut out from it. How can i do this? I tried many different ways but nothing worked very well. I've attached an image of bottle in Blender. The pattern I want to cut out is the photo I've used as background image.[image]

[The Blender file](http://www.filedropper.com/kikkoman)

Comment: Like almost an indent into the bottle?  If so, perhaps the boolean modifier would help?

Comment: Can you upload your .blend and edit your question with the link using blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com please? Also, as a side note, it looks like your normals are inverted.

Comment: Try to spot if your bottle's body shape has some regular/symmetric pattern repeating, or if it is more like an organic/irregular shape. Each situation has different solving paths...

Comment: Thanks for answers, well i am very new to blender, but yes its indent in the bottle that goes around in a special shape, This is the photo i use as reference, http://www.wellbusiness.at/upload/editor/Kikkoman%20Sojasauce_500ml-DE%20KLEIN.jpg (maybe thats what made you think normals was inverted "luka ash"?) i try edit my question with the .blend file i use, i hope image also get included (not done this before).

Comment: I right now looking at tutorial of boolean modifier, seems like something that could work :) i am trying to learn, so not familiar with all different ways doing stuff in blender (also new to 3d modelling then) thats why i ask a question like this, to get advices.

Answer (score 3):

The secret is to model the indentations first, then use a deformer to create the twist.

1. Start with a cylinder with 9 sides.  Bevel (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd>) the edges and add an edge loop top and bottom, this will be the lip of the indentation.
2. Select the sides that will be indented.  Use polygon inset tool (<kbd>I</kbd>) to make them inset and indented.

[image]

3. Add a Simple Deform modifier.  Adjust the angle to meet the reference image.

[image]

4. Add a Subdivision Surface modifier and preview the result.  Apply the deformation modifier.
5. Select top and bottom edge loops.  Use the LoopTools Circle tool (this requires the LoopTools addon).

[image]

6. Extrude (<kbd>E</kbd>) the top and bottom faces and model the rest of the bottle.

[image]

Comment: Thanks allot for that answer Xtremity, even though i dont have a clue about all the terms you are using in the explanation :D, i need learn about them i guess and step by step follow what you said. Your picture looks exactly what i want to do :D. I will google and youtube and see if i can understand all you said. Thanks!

Comment: Can i just ask a little more to help me understand the idea of your solution? the cylinder you start with (9 sides) is that a extra cylinder i make for making the shape of the indent? and in nr:2 you say "Select the sides that will be indented" on the bottle model? or the extra cylinder? sorry if stupid questions but as i said i try to learn :D.

Comment: I think i just figured it out lol. You started the whole bottle project with making this shape, from different tools, and then extruded the bottom part and top part of the bottom. Am i wrong?. That helped me any how. Thanks allot.

Comment: Hey, I've added some screencasts that hopefully explain the answer a bit better.

Comment: Thanks my friend you are the best :). Very instructive! did not use the loop tool but had it very nice any way. Thanks allot for your help.