# How to make rounded indents in objects

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, objects, edit-mode

I am looking to make details on the handle of a sword, and am trying to use the Boolean modifier to cut into the cylindrical handle. Unfortunately, Blender does not seem to enjoy cutting the objects when the subdivision surface modifier is high detail. I would like for the curves to look smooth. Is there another way for me to create these rounded cutouts or am I using Boolean wrong? The Blend File: https://we.tl/t-8ZrO9rS824

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Here's a video on fixing artifacts with booleans that may be of help to you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0T3QdLJOBF8

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52488/how-can-i-model-indentations-on-a-surface/52515#52515

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos It would be rather difficult to acquire my desired shape with this method

Comment: @stphnl329 This video shows that adding geometry can fix artifacts when using boolean, but my issue is that boolean doesn't work even with a lot of geometry

Comment: Just noticed something, have you tried moving the booleans before the subsurf modifier?

Comment: @stphnl329 Yes I have tried this. The subsurf ruins the crisp edges of the cut. I have attached the file for you to play around with

Comment: Say do you happen to have discord? It'll probably be easier to communicate over that. My disc is stphnl329#8530. We can also open up a SE chat if that's better. There's a lot of general modelling tips to go over looking at that.

Comment: @stphnl329 I have actually found a solution, although I do not know why. I was using a cube with subserf but I switched to a sphere, ensuring that the point node is inside the mesh and this seems to work without issue. I am guessing Blender gets confused when the object doesn't have main nodes inside the cut object, but only subserf nodes. If you have any more ideas msg me on discord its LightOfTheNight#3346

Comment: @stphnl329 okay nvm. That method worked for the lower cut but it didn't like the shape of the higher cut

Comment: Alright, I'll msg you on Discord

Comment: why are you subsurfacing your boolean object? You should get remove this modifier, then apply the Boolean, then bring some topology correction to the handle, then give this handle a Subsurf